# How can I add custom fields to contacts info in iphone contact list

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am developing a app in which I have to add custom contacts to iPhone Contact list.

To elaborate that every contact in iPhone have a definite set of fields which we can be  used to save contact info.

I want to know if we can

**add custom fields apart from that ofexisting options in iPhone.**

If its possible please show me the way to do that, googled it but didn't found any thing meaningfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all the below given solutions are jst for adding details to contact list.

I want help for adding custon fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12496-add-contact-address-book.html).

```
ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate(); 
    CFErrorRef  anError = NULL; 
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, 
                     CFSTR("Jijo"), &anError); 
    ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, 
                     CFSTR("Pulikkottil"), &anError); 
    if (anError != NULL) { 

        NSLog(@"error while creating..");
    } 
    CFStringRef firstName, lastName; 
    firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty); 
    lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty); 




    ABAddressBookRef addressBook; 
    CFErrorRef error = NULL; 
    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 

    BOOL isAdded = ABAddressBookAddRecord (
                            addressBook,
                            aRecord,
                             &error
    );

    if(isAdded){

        NSLog(@"added..");
    }
    if (error != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookAddRecord %@", error);
    } 
    error = NULL;

    BOOL isSaved = ABAddressBookSave (
                       addressBook,
                       &error
    );

    if(isSaved){

        NSLog(@"saved..");
    }

    if (error != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookSave %@", error);
    } 

    CFRelease(aRecord); 
    CFRelease(firstName); 
    CFRelease(lastName); 
    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

If you need to store data in there, I think your only option is `kABPersonNoteProperty`, but I'm no expert on this.

Edit: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418319/does-iphone-support-adding-custom-properties-to-address-book-records).

Answer: nope!

Edit: you can also prompt the user to add an address book entry as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041410/how-to-get-around-lack-of-add-button-in-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to programmatically add custom fields to the iPhone address book, even in iOS 5.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this out!

[How to add a "Custom Label" to iOS AddressBook programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675783/how-to-add-a-custom-label-to-iphone-addressbook-programmaticly)

Working 100% in iOS 6. Tested!