# iPhone Address Book custom property

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am developing an application which is similar to native contact book app of iphone. I want to add additional property/field in native iphone address book database. e.g. network carrier of each contact (AT&T).

How to access the database of native address book from our app? Is that possible to do?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add custom fields to contacts info in iphone contact list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747109/how-can-i-add-custom-fields-to-contacts-info-in-iphone-contact-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot add custom fields. You can add data into the Notes field, but not add any custom fields into the AddressBook Person class. You can extend the AddressBook but you will need to save the data somewhere else and link the Person to the data you saved.

You can access the data from the address book using the [AddressBook framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/index.html).

Comment: I want to add new column in native address book database. I am able to edit structure of sqlite db of address book in simulator (e.g added new column in ABPersonRecord table). I've not tested this in iPhone device yet.

Will apple approve this or will reject?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd be very wary of that. It could fall in the area of "private" apis. And that is often if not always rejected at some point once discovered.

Comment: I found a method addPropertiesAndTypes: to add new properties in address book for each contact. But I am not able to find any proper reference code for that. If you have experience with that then please let me know.

Comment: Pretty sure that'd be considered a private API if there's no documentation.  I'd avoid that at all costs.  No need to run a risk of rejection, eh? :)

Answer (score 4):

addPropertiesAndTypes is only available on Mac OS